# Could not parse auth token (Firebase)

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I am trying to save data in my firebase realtime database using this rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I need to create a child of users and name it the uid of that user. So, I did this:

```
user=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password('email', 'password')
database.child('users').child(user['localId']).set("nahid",user['localId'])
```

but when I run this, I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://khelobd-6f730-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/7Km7srPfqqccZwa0On5i2QaJDUi2.json?auth=7Km7srPfqqccZwa0On5i2QaJDUi2] {
  "error" : "Could not parse auth token."
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `?auth=` param does not seems to be user's Firebase ID Token but the UID itself. Try changing `user['localId']` in `set()` to `user['idToken']`:

```
user=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password('email', 'password')
database.child('users').child(user['localId']).set("nahid",user['idToken'])
#                                                                  ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. You just saved me!!!